# How to order vertices in an acyclic digraph?

Tags: graph-theory, induction

If $G$ is an acyclic digraph on $n$ vertices, how can I show that the vertices of $G$ can be
ordered as $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n$ so that if $v_iv_j$ is an edge in $G$, then $i<j$? I have considered using a proof by induction but I'm not sure what the inductive hypothesis would be.

Comment: *topological sort*

Answer (score 1):

If there are no cycles, there should be a vertex with only incoming edges (and no outgoing edges). This might be your "last" vertex.